# using import and dynamic import() to load the same module

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, import

i'm using webpack to bundle my react app, i'm trying to dynamically import external libraries so it can can be cached without needing to load it every time the code changes .

so i import react in every component like this `import React from 'react';`
and import it in the app.jsx dynamically `import(/* webpackChunkName: "react" */ 'react');`

my question is will that lead to duplicate react bundles ?
PS: i don't want to change `import React` to `import('react')` in every single file ,is that possible to avoid?

#### webpack config

```
module.exports = {
mode: 'production',
cache: false,
entry: {
    index: ['babel-polyfill', './client/src/app.jsx'],
},
optimization: {
    minimizer: [new TerserPlugin({
    parallel: true,
    sourceMap: true,
    terserOptions: {
        mangle: true,
        safari10: true,
        compress: {},
        warnings: false,
        ecma: 6,
        output: {
        comments: false,
        },
    },
    })],
},
devtool: 'source-map',
output: {
    path: `${rootPath}/server-dist/public/`,
    filename: '[name].[contenthash].bundle.js',
    chunkFilename: '[name].[contenthash].bundle.js',
    publicPath: '/',
},
module: {
    rules: [
    // compile js
    {
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        options: {
            presets: ['react', 'es2015', 'stage-2'],
            plugins: ['react-hot-loader/babel', ['module-resolver', {
            alias: {
                common: './common',
            },
            }]],
            babelrc: false,
        },
        },
    },
    // compile sass
    {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        use: [
        MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
        'css-loader', 'resolve-url-loader', 'postcss-loader?sourceMap', 'sass-loader?sourceMap',
        ],

    },
    // load images
    {
        test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif|svg)$/i,
        use: [
        'file-loader?hash=sha512&digest=hex&name=assets/img/[name].[ext]',
        {
            loader: 'image-webpack-loader',
            query: {
            mozjpeg: {
                progressive: true,
            },
            gifsicle: {
                interlaced: true,
            },
            optipng: {
                optimizationLevel: 7,
            },
            },
        },
        ],
    },
    // load fonts
    {
        test: /\.(ttf|eot|svg|woff(2)?)(\?[a-z0-9=&.]+)?$/,
        use: 'file-loader?name=assets/fonts/[name].[ext]',

    },
    {
        test: require.resolve('blueimp-file-upload'),
        loader: 'imports-loader?define=>false',
    },
    {
        test: require.resolve('medium-editor-insert-plugin'),
        loader: 'imports-loader?define=>false',
    },
    ],
},
resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js', '.jsx'],
    alias: {
    'jquery-ui/widget$': 'jquery-ui/ui/widget',
    },
},
plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
    inject: true,
    template: `${rootPath}/client/index.html`,
    }),
    new webpack.IgnorePlugin(/^\.\/locale$/, /moment$/),
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
    jQuery: 'jquery',
    $: 'jquery',
    jquery: 'jquery',
    }),
    new webpack.EnvironmentPlugin(['TEST']),
    extractSass,
],
node: {
    dgram: 'empty',
    fs: 'empty',
    net: 'empty',
    tls: 'empty',
    child_process: 'empty',
},
};
```

Comment: Does your `app.js` load your components (e.g., via `import`)?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder yes i use import normally

Comment: I can't help with how Webpack handles this, but just FYI if you were using modules natively, each `import()` acts like the starting point of an import tree (just like your HTML with `<script type="import"...>` does, since it's your entry point using static `import`). So you'd have two copies of React loaded (one shared by all the static imports in the tree rooted in your HTML, and a second copy loaded by `app.js` dynamically). But again, I don't know if Webpack does it that way (although it should, to be faithful to the spec, since that's an observable behavior).